# How to filter out parameters value in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I currently have a SSRS report which is giving me Telephony Data based on two sites, Cape Town and Dallas.

At present I have a parameter called Site and a parameter called Data_Label. It works absolutely how I wish by selecting Cape Town and the relevant Data_Label and the same for Dallas. This then shows all the data I need.

The issue I have is that there is a very long list of Data_Label's, half are attached to the Cape Town site and the other half to the Dallas site. What I would like to have happen, is when I select Cape Town as my site, half of the Data_Label's appear and then when I select Dallas the others will then show.

This is my current query in the Dataset:

**WHERE ([LB ODS].Telephony_LifestyleBenefits_VIEW.Site IN (@Site)) AND ([LB ODS].DataLookup.Data_Label IN (@DataLabel))**

So each Data_Label will be linked to it's relevant site in the main database but I just need a filter in my parameter so that it doesn't show the long list

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Can you join Data_Label and Site datasets? If I understand your issue this can be solved by cascading both parameters.

Comment: I only have 1 dataset in use at the moment, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: How are you populating Data_Label and Site parameters?

Comment: I've just manually typed them in as the available values

Comment: I think you can conditionally populate the Data_Label parameter based on the Site selection. But you have to provide a way to tell if every Data_Label value is related to Cape Town or Dallas. Edit your question to include the list of Data_Label values and the corresponding Site value.

Comment: In my database there is a join which takes the Data_Label's from Table 2 and then assigns them to a site in Table 1 so every label has some site attached in the VIEW which is being used for all the data

Comment: I see the problem is your Data_Label parameter is showing a list containing all values, but you want to show only the values related to Site parameter value. The problem is related to the way you populate Data_Label parameter since you have to check Site value before in order to generate the filtered out list of available values. Which values are you manually typing in each parameter?

Comment: Cascading Parameters worked! - I managed to create two extra datasets, one called Site and one called Data_Label and it works perfectly.

Thanks for the tip Alejandro!

Comment: Alejandro, is there any chance you could just answer the question with 'the use of cascading parameters' so I can close the question off with positive feedback.

Thanks once again for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cascade `Data_Label` parameter from Site parameter value.

If you populate `Data_Label` parameter via a dataset you can filter the available values using the `Site` parameter, something like this

```
select Data_Label
from Table1
where Site IN (@Site)
```

When you run the report the dataset that populates the `Data_Label` parameter will run the above query and return the Data_Label values related to the value selected for the `Site` parameter.

Also if you populate the parameter manually you can hardcode the values in a CTE what results in something like this:

```
WITH DLValues AS (

select 'Data_Label1' [Data_Label], 'Dallas' [RelatedSite]
union all
select 'Data_Label2' [Data_Label], 'Dallas' [RelatedSite]
union all
select 'Data_Label3' [Data_Label], 'Cape Town' [RelatedSite]
union all
select 'Data_Label4' [Data_Label], 'Cape Town' [RelatedSite]

) 

select Data_Label
from DLValues
where RelatedSite IN (@Site)
```

Let me know if this helps you.